# C# conversion from list<decimal> to double array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, casting

This is NET 4.5, so feel free to go crazy with the ideas. =)

I have a very large decimal List, and I need to convert it to an array of doubles.  The kicker here is that due to the list size, I want it to be all done in one pass...O(n)

I can do it with two passes, but that makes it O(2n), which is really time intensive and probably unnecessary.

I've been banging my head against this for a couple of hours now, and it's just not clicking.  I've used ConvertAll, ToArray, Convert, Lambdas, linq, delegates, you name it.  It is seriously not clicking in my head.

Somebody, anybody, show me how its done so I can kick myself and get on with my day.  =P

Comment: `decimals.Select(d => Convert.ToDouble(d)).ToArray()`?  Is that not performant enough?  What have you tried and why did it not work?

Comment: Also note that converting between `double` and `decimal` *usually* means you should have picked one or the other type and used it consistently. It's rare that a value is appropriate to store in both types.

Comment: There is no thing such as O(2n). 2 is a constant and will be eliminated in Big-Oh notation. But anyway, we know what you mean.

Comment: The fact that you want to convert a list to an array and you only know of ways that take at least two passes amazes me.

Comment: @Renan Share some of the other ways.

Comment: @MichaelMinton see Marko's answer. It takes only one pass. You shouldn't need more than one. Taking more than one pass through the list is a sign of overthinking or overengineering.

Comment: @Renan Agreed. I think your second comment will provide more insight for the OP that perhaps he's way overthinking things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about a simple for loop?

```
var ary = new double[list.Count];
for (var ii = 0; ii < list.Count; ii++) {
 ary[ii] = Convert.ToDouble(list[ii]);
}
```

EDIT: I strongly believe that LINQ is the right way to go. It's short, precise and clean.

```
var ary = list.Select(item => Convert.ToDouble(item)).ToArray();
```

Comment: That's crazy talk - given all the advanced capabilities of .net 4.5 and you spit out a basic for loop?! <- This demonstrates why, often times, the most strait forward solution really is the best. Good job. =)

Comment: Personally, I would choose LINQ - it's waaay simpler.
Since the question implicitly ruled that out, for loop was the only remaining choice

Comment: It's way simpler for people who have a solid understanding of language integrated queries, sure.

Comment: With Linq you can get rid of the lambda if you like, so `list.Select(Convert.ToDouble).ToArray()`. However, I would do `list.Select(i => (double)i).ToArray()`.

Comment: I appreciate your comment and completely agree with you. It's just a personal preference, I'd say. As long as we agree LINQ is the right choice, all the rest is just nitpicking.